# Grub doesn't detect my windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, uefi

It is my first time installing Ubuntu (14.04). 
I have Windows 7 installed on my first HDD, and installed ubuntu on my second one.

To install I followed the instructions on this website:
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/05/31/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-windows-7-on-a-pc-with-2-hdds-and-uefi-firmware/

I hit Esc during boot and Grub only shows Ubuntu and Advanced options.
However if I enter boot menu on my BIOS I can click on the name of my first HDD and it boots straight to windows.

How can I get Grub to show my Windows 7?

One more thing which seems wrong:
After loading up Ubuntu I first get this message:

[   10.040229] systemd-undevd[343]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE: Invalid Arguments.

then it boots normally to my Ubuntu log in screen.

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Most Windows 7 systems were BIOS installed. Are you sure yours was UEFI? Both systems have to be installed in same boot mode either UEFI or both BIOS for grub menu to be able to boot Windows.

Comment: Mine is UEFI, I put it together myself. I am not sure if I installed W7 in UEFI mode. How do I find out?

Comment: If Windows drive is gpt then it has to be UEFI, if MBR(msdos) then it has to be BIOS. Also if you have an efi partition then it is UEFI. Post this for sda. sudo parted -l and sudo fdisk -lu If gpt the fdisk will only show that it is gpt and not show any detail.

Comment: Do I type in sudo parted -l sda and similar for fdisk in the terminal? Sorry, I am very new to this!

Comment: just 'sudo parted -l' without quotes will work. That is an el, not one - 1  or eye - I.

Comment: @oldfred I am not sure what I am looking for, but here is the pastebin link. http://pastebin.com/KvubqGHK

Comment: Your Windows install has to be BIOS, it has MBR partitioning on sda and Windows only boots with BIOS from MBR or only boots with UEFI from gpt. Also you have the standard 100MB boot and main install, not an efi partition on sda nor the system reserved partition that UEFI Windows required. So you cannot dual boot from grub menu but only from UEFI/BIOS or one time boot key. Not sure if Ubuntu is UEFI or not as with MBR you usually do not use UEFI. UEFI normally uses gpt partitioning.

Comment: Should I just leave it like that then? I won't be losing out on anything?

Comment: It should work fine, just you cannot use grub menu for choosing boot, but use one time boot key or UEFI/BIOS. At some point in future you may want to reinstall a Windows and then I would consider converting. But otherwise a major install with very little gain.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for all the help you've provided :)

Answer (score 0):

try entering ubuntu, open the terminal and type "sudo update-grub", maybe after this you can see windows on your boot menu.

Comment: I tried this and nothing changed.